# Something similar like <?php echo $_GET['height'];?> in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im wondering if there is a function or something like php's `<?php echo $_GET['height'];?>` but in HTML or javascript.
I need it to get variables of the URL

Comment: You can find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values#answer-901144

Answer (score 0):

Use `location.search`. It returns the entire query string, which you then can split, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Html is a markup language, so you can't do such things.
Try using javascript.
here's an example:

```
//returns the height of the client
function height(){
   var clientHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
   alert(clientHeight);
```

}